# Show messages from table for specific userid

Tags: php, mysql

I've built a simple messaging system that uses 5 columns

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ID (INT) | toid (INT) | fromid (INT) | message (TEXT) | datetime (datetime stamp)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

and I am currently using the following query to show all the messages for the logged in user

```
SELECT m.fromid as messageid,
photo, forename, surname, m.status, datetime, m.type, message, timestamp
FROM messages m 
LEFT JOIN users ON users.userID = m.fromid
WHERE toid ='106' 
GROUP BY fromid
ORDER BY datetime DESC
```

At the moment the query only shows messages once the person replies back to a message (this is because of the `WHERE toid = '106'`

I am wondering what the correct query would be to show messages for when a conversation is started by the **users id '106'**

Comment: _the query only shows messages once the person replies back to a message_ Because you are using `GROUP BY fromid` remove groupby you'll get all messages

Comment: Issue is without groupid it shows every single message that the user has received, instead of grouping them into one.

Also the WHERE toid, is also causing a conflict as in some instances the fromid will be 106 and the toid will be different

Comment: the use of groupby is only with aggregate `sum,group_concat` functions...also if you want to retrieve all messages then it doesn't make any sense here.

Comment: What do you mean _grouping them into one_ ?

Comment: _in some instances the fromid will be 106 and the toid will be different_ you can use `or`... `WHERE toid ='106'  OR fromid='106'`